# add total sum of rows in a datagridview in a label

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, label

I have a label as a Subtitle, in this label i want to display the number of rows in datagridview.

i added this line of code but it just returns a 0 not the amount of rows in the datagridview.

```
 private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        lblTitle.Text = _settings.set;
        lblSubtitle.Text = dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString();
 }
```

why is it displaying only a 0?

Comment: Most probably you get the RowCount before binding the DataGridView as there is no code for binding the DataGridView before getting the count.

Comment: What do you need exactly? Sum of all values in a column or count of rows?

Comment: @RezaAghaei count of rows

Answer (score 1):

1. Requirement
2. DataGridView
3. Select Column Name Which you want to sum
4. A Label need in which you save the Result
5. SelectAmount is Label

   private void function()
     {

   ```
           int SelectResult = 0;
           if (DataSelector.RowCount != 0)
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < DataSelector.RowCount; i++)
               {
                   bool value = false;
                   if (DataSelector.Rows[i].Cells["Select"].Value != null)
                   {
                       value = (bool)DataSelector.Rows[i].Cells["Select"].Value;
                       if (value)
                       {

                              int ar = 0;
                              bool r = int.TryParse(DataSelector.Rows[i].Cells["Paid"].Value.ToString(), out ar);
                               if (r)
                               {
                                   SelectResult += ar;
                               }
                       }

                   }
               }

           }
               SelectAmount.Text = SelectResult.ToString();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RowsAdded` and `RowsRemoved` events for updating label with new value

```
public class YourForm
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UpdateSubtitle(); // Display initial value

        dataGridView1.RowsAdded += (sender, args) => UpdateSubtitle();
        dataGridView1.RowsRemoved += (sender, args) => UpdateSubtitle();
    }

    private void UpdateSubtitle()
    {
        lblSubtitle.Text = dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString();
    }
}
```